# Draw AWT/Swing components indirectly?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, lwjgl

I wanna know... is there a way to draw the components style outside from [Frame](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html&ei=77QaUZqkB4ba9ATOjICoDA&usg=AFQjCNFgjMK1YXjYV6Jorq2K7_Qh-R4U5A&sig2=3QdTuwNqpD3VPe0TBpHAAw&bvm=bv.42261806,d.eWU)/[Applet](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html&ei=ArUaUaynHYO69gTQiIGwCQ&usg=AFQjCNEWTVYfoAsPN4EZQ11f-WY0TuSvpg&sig2=m4IWAjVF6JgIZlgBjHeNzw&bvm=bv.42261806,d.eWU)?
I'm making a application that uses [OpenGL](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.lwjgl.org/&ei=EbUaUcbeM4aS9QS1r4CYCA&usg=AFQjCNE8oAPs9T1BnFKkSYtgX-4tQw2lKw&sig2=5WqeBVYCknIW9W1qCazqXg&bvm=bv.42261806,d.eWU), and I need a [GUI](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface&ei=HbUaUfv0CJOY9QSp44CQBA&usg=AFQjCNF23sgnTImh2Exsyl44XrmkXlwmmA&sig2=So02Gh5NenzqL6bCxS_Onw&bvm=bv.42261806,d.eWU) with a good look, like AWT or Swing. Yes, I know that there are many libraries like [Nifty](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/&ei=0LQaUa6lPIXe8AT1-YHwBg&usg=AFQjCNG60pRpdHY9hAgpbVA2qx3f_n2EdA&sig2=Qc5EWo1Bm0YAd1-cRrj3Dw&bvm=bv.42261806,d.eWU) and [TWL](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAB&url=http://twl.l33tlabs.org/&ei=37QaUcnMKoa08ASwjIGYBA&usg=AFQjCNHYjlvXN_K5izOIO7rjyf1__AwTbQ&sig2=_uLFcKy-RB6kQFe22mhCcQ&bvm=bv.42261806,d.eWU), but I really want use AWT/Swing look.

Thanks. (And sorry for my bad english, I'm brazilian.)

Comment: What do you mean by "draw the components style outside from Frame/Applet"? You want to customize the look of the AWT components?

Comment: Or you want nice OpenGL components inside your OpenGL image?

Comment: Basically, I want draw a component (like Button) without adding it to a Frame or Applet (it is, draw a AWT button on OpenGL, but without using Frame or Applet).

Comment: Component should be added to any container in order to display itself. I'm absolutely sure, that your OpenGL control is added to JFrame/Applet in order to display itself.

Comment: Well, there is a way to add the OpenGL display to a Canvas, so I'll take a look on that. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a component to an image, even if it is not displayable (although you will have to manually set the size to the preferred size):

```
c.setSize(c.getPreferredSize());
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), 
      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
c.paintComponent(g);
g.dispose();
```

You can then use that image as a texture in OpenGL.

Of course, this will only give you a picture of the component; you won't be able to interact with it as you could with a "real" swing component.

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I was searching for! Thank you a lot.